# How do you form differential maps in a quotient complex? (Weibel pg. 5)

Tags: homological-algebra

They say "...In this case we can assemble the quotient modules $C_n / B_n$ into a chain complex 
$$ \cdots \xrightarrow{d} C_{n+1}/B_{n+1} \xrightarrow{d} C_{n}/B_{n} \xrightarrow{d} \cdots $$

But how is each $d_n$ defined?

My attempt shows that $d_n : C_n/B_n \to C_{n-1}/B_{n-1}$ defined by mapping $x + B_n \to d_n^{(C)}(x) + B_{n-1}$.  I've shown on paper that it is a indeed a differential of the sequence.  I haven't proven well-definedness though.  $x + B_n = y + B_n \implies  d_n^{(C)}(x - y) \in B_{n-1} \implies$ ?

Here's complete info from the book:

[image]

Comment: I dont have Weibel. please give more information, or a picture.

Comment: $x + B_n = y + B_n \implies  d_n^{(C)}(x - y) \in B_{n-1} \implies d_n^{(C)}(x )- d_n^{(C)}(y) \in B_{n-1} \implies   d_n^{(C)}(x) + B_{n-1}= d_n^{(C)}(y) + B_{n-1}$

Comment: @user1  that seems simple enough.  I usually see those types of tricks right away.  I must have been tired last night.

Comment: I could guess; you are above 5k. BTW, the comment may help others that will read the question.